# CheckBox concatenando string varias vezes

Tags: c#, sql, .net, string, winforms

[image: Aplicaçao]

Eu queria que ao clicar nos *checkbox* e depois em registrar, salvasse no banco o valor já predefinido e o nome do serviço (descrição).

Porém, a descrição esta sendo um problema para mim, porque quando o usuário marca e desmarca varias vezes a *checkbox*, ele acaba concatenando mais do que o esperado.

E se ele marcar, depois desmarcar, a descrição ainda continua contendo o valor da opção desmarcada.

Eu sei que isso acontece porque `Checked == true` vai acontecer varias vezes,eu tentei realizar a concatenação fora do método, mas não consegui.

[image: SS]

Banco : 
 [image: SS]

Comment: Quando for colocar código prefira sempre postar como texto e não como imagem. Ajuda as pessoas aproveitarem seu código em alguns casos para ajudar melhor você. Além disto ajuda outras pessoas achar o que precisam na sua pergunta quando usam buscadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do principio de que `descricao_servico` só é necessária quando for clicado o botão registar.

Declare uma `List<string>` para guardar cada item da descrição, depois percorra essa lista para compor a descrição:

```
List<string> itensdescrição = new List<string>();
```

Em cada um dos métodos CheckedChanged:

```
if(cb_serv_pe.Checked)
{
    itensDescricao.Add("unha pé");
    this.servico = this.servico + 1;
}
else
{
    itensDescricao.Remove("unha pé");
    this.servico = this.servico - 1;
}
```

No método do botão ***Registar***

```
//Limpa a descrição
descricao_servico = "";

//Percorre a lista e compõe a descrição
foreach (var item in itensDescrição)
{
    descricao_servico = descricao_servico + item + ",";
}

//Remove a última virgula
descricao_servico = descricao_servico.Remove(descricao_servico.Length - 1);

//Limpa a lista caso seja necessário utilizá-la outra vez
itensDescricao.Clear();
```

Comment: A parte de montar a string é só meter um `string.Join(",", itensDescrição)`, n?

Comment: @Francisco, sim, pode usar isso em vez do **foreach** usado na resposta.

Answer (score 2):

É muito simples resolver isto e talvez outros problemas que você não percebeu que acontece por causa do mesmo erro. Mas exige uma mudança arquitetural.

## O problema

Todo o formulário, não só este controle específico, tem diversos eventos. Cada um tem uma finalidade. Antes de usar cada um você deve se perguntar se aquele evento é realmente o que você quer usar como disparador de alguma ação.

Por que você precisa que ele gere a *string* a ser usada cada vez que um clique seja dado? O clique não deveria gerar uma ação assim.

Na verdade esse é um erro comum. Os programadores costumam validar no próprio controle, mas em geral a validação deveria ser feita no final do processo de cadastro. Muitas vezes você nem consegue validar direito enquanto está no meio do cadastro. Quantas vezes eu fiquei com raiva porque o formulário não me deixava sair de um controle que não era válido mas para eu deixar válido eu precisava ir para outro controle.

Eventos de controles devem ser usados para ações que **só podem** ser feitas dentro dele. Qualquer coisa que pode ser feita fora do controle específico, deve ser feita fora dele, deve ser feita quando o processo está se concluindo, quando está encerrando o formulário em condições normais ou alguma ação determina o final do processo de cadastro. Isto vale para validações e preparação de dados antes gravar no banco de dados.

Não existe razão para preparar dados para gravar antes dos dados estarem em estado definitivo para gravação.

Na verdade alguma coisa me diz que o problema é maior que isto. Eu ainda tenho dúvidas se deveria montar uma *string* para gravar no banco de dados, me parece uma solução errada, mas como não é o foco da pergunta vou deixar você pensar nisto. Especialmente me parece algo errado para se fazer durante o formulário. Provavelmente o formulário deveria atualizar uma classe com os dados e não se preocupar com a persistência de dados. Cada um deveria cuidar da sua função real, cada um deveria ter uma só responsabilidade.

## A solução

Então no evento adequado você varre todos os *checkbox* que precisam ser avaliado e monta a *string* que você precisa. Assim não terá mais esse problema.

Tem jeito de resolver isto de outra forma mas a mais correta é esta que eu te passei.

Acredito que o evento correto a ser usado seja o [`FormClosing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) mas é bom dar uma olhada em todos e ver se existe algum mais adequado. Eventualmente você pode disparar este processo através de um botão de "salvar" também. Por isto provavelmente o processo de finalização deveria estar em um método que pode ser chamado de vários lugares já que pode existir mais de uma forma de encerrar o processo de cadastro.

Se preferir separar as responsabilidades, que é o correto, então o que você deveria fazer é atualizar a classe que representa o o dado a ser cadastro ao invés de se preocupar com a *string* que vai para o banco de dados (que provavelmente deveria ser gravado de outra forma). Na verdade se isto fosse feito o evento do *checkbox* até **poderia** ser usado para a atualizar o objeto que sustenta do dado. Ainda não seria o mais correto mas daria certo.